# dockerhub automated builds appear to cache access to other github repositories

Tags: r, dockerhub

My Dockerfile includes a step that pulls from an unrelated, public git repository. Specifically, it's installing an R package using the R command

```
devtools::install_github("bmbroom/NGCHMR")
```

This should install the latest version of the package from the master branch of that repository, and on local builds that is exactly what it does.

On Dockerhub automated builds, however, I always get the version of the package that was current when I first built the image.  There is otherwise nothing special about that particular version.  It's as if github access is being cached.  The docker build process itself is clearly not cached, based on authoritative replies to other questions here as well as the build logs, which show earlier steps in the build being executed in detail.

Any suggestions why I'm not getting the most recent version of the R package installed?

Comment: Stupid error on my part.  I was pulling the updated image but running an incorrect version (dangers of using bash history).